# XpathExpression with Java collection parameter

Tags: java, xpath

having such a collection in java {"0","1","true","false"} i'd like to select all book where attribute 'available' is in my collection.

Exemple of XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books:booklist
    xmlns:books="http://univNaSpResolver/booklist"
    xmlns="http://univNaSpResolver/book"
    xmlns:fiction="http://univNaSpResolver/fictionbook">
    <science:book xmlns:science="http://univNaSpResolver/sciencebook">
        <title>Learning XPath</title>
        <author>Michael Schmidt</author>
        <available>1</available>
    </science:book>
    <fiction:book>
        <title>Faust I</title>
        <author>Johann Wolfgang von Goethe</author>
        <available>maybe</available>
    </fiction:book>
    <fiction:book>
        <title>Faust II</title>
        <author>Johann Wolfgang von Goethe</author>
        <available>true</available>
    </fiction:book>
</books:booklist>
```

It seems that using contains function can do this but i don't know how to use a list as parameter in XPath (for java).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the concrete Java code but to check whether an element contains one of a list or collection of values in XPath 1.0 you usually create a string from the list or collection with a separator not contained in the values e.g. your collection `{"0","1","true","false"}` becomes `|0|1|true|false|` (where I have chosen the bar character `|` as the separator character) and then you compare e.g. `//book[contains($list, concat('|', available, '|'))]`.

Obviously your input is more complicated as it uses namespaces and that way has (at least?) two different elements you are looking for and the `available` element also is in a namespace.

So assuming a namespace mapping of  `xmlns:science="http://univNaSpResolver/sciencebook"`, `xmlns:fiction="http://univNaSpResolver/fictionbook"` and `xmlns:book="http://univNaSpResolver/book"` the XPath could look like

```
//science:book[contains('|0|1|true|false|', concat('|', book:available, '|'))] |
//fiction:book[contains('|0|1|true|false|', concat('|', book:available, '|'))]
```

Of course it is advisable to pass in the string of values as a parameter so that you would get e.g.

```
//science:book[contains($list, concat('|', book:available, '|'))] |
//fiction:book[contains($list, concat('|', book:available, '|'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

the [contains(string1,string2)](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string) function available in XPath is merely a String comparison that

> Returns true if string1 contains string2, otherwise it returns false

you can always join predicates with an [OR](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp) operator:

```
//science:book[available="true" or available="false" or available="1" or available="0"] |
//fiction:book[available="true" or available="false" or available="1" or available="0"]
```

Comment: Yeahh, this solution is so elegant and so simple. Thanks a lot.